# Error: POCO handler Connection reset by peer

Tags: c++, sockets, connection, poco, poco-libraries

I am using POCO libraries for socket connection. I am getting connection reset by peer exception. I tried to reconnect to the socket using the following code:

```
   try
   {
        socket.sendBytes(outBuffer.data(),outBuffer.available());
   }
   catch (const Poco::Exception& exc)
   {
        socket.close()
        std::string host = "localhost";
        uint16_t port = 5672;
        const Poco::Net::SocketAddress address(host, port);
        socket.connect(address);
        socket.setKeepAlive(true);
   }
```

But while calling `sendBytes()` function from `Poco::Net::StreamSocket` I am getting same exception after reconnecting too. Can anyone suggest me something on this ?

Comment: see what the server is doing. If you don't have access to server, use  `tcpdump` or `WinDump` to record traffic and review the recorded exchange using [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)